# Android Debugger Source Not Found For Local Files

Tags: android, eclipse, debugging

I'm working with Android and trying to step through some code I've created with the Eclipse Juno Debugger, but when my breakpoint is hit the debugger the loads MyClassFile$1.onClick(View) instead of MyClassFile. I moved the break point to the onCreate method and it breaks at MyClassFile.onCreate(Bundle), but it still says Source not found. I can even see the MyClassFile tabbed up in Debug View and occasionally even see the highlighted line from the breakpoint.

When I step through I can see the local variables I've created and some of the values are updating as I step through, but it's not stepping through the same file.

The code doesn't reside in a .jar but are files within my project, created locally but they are hooked up to a remote SVN Repository. I'm using Eclipse Juno with subversive. Has anyone else had this issue?

Edit - 
All I had to do was go in to Attach Source and then click add. One of the options is a work space folder and I added the src folder that held all of my classes and it's working fine now.